# MediaWiki Login Page for Non Logged In Users

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a way to make a login page that just asks for user/pass for MediaWiki so they don't see the sidebar or a page that says they have to login to view the content?

Any links to examples and/or tutorials would be awesome, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting down voted for this question. Seems like a perfectly reasonable feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probaby http authentication is what you need. [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAutomaticREMOTE_USER) has example on how to do that.

Comment: I saw that, I'm not hosting the wiki for a networked domain though. I just have it on the internet and just want a page with a login before it shows the you must be logged in to view this content page.

Comment: so you want two authentication. one authentication before the mediawiki page is shown and once authenticated, then user should authenticate itself again using mediawiki authentication method?

Comment: No just one authentication but I don't want people to see the MediaWiki layout at all. Kind of like when you log into the admin side of WordPress or Joomla you just see the login page. Same if you try and access a URL on the admin side of those it just redirects to the login page.